# I wrote a script to download a multiple excel files using ruby watir

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

The script is working fine for me.
Now, Iam downloading 500 files at a time.
I want to download the files by specifying some range like (10-30) files at one time and (30-60) at another time so on using ruby watir.
These is my code:

```
require 'watir'
require 'rubygems'

begin
  chromedriver_path = File.join(File.absolute_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)),"browser","chromedriver.exe")
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = chromedriver_path
  browser = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
  browser.goto "" //url to login
  sleep 3
  browser.text_field(:name=>"").set "" #e_id
  sleep 3
  browser.text_field(:name=>"").set "" #pwd
  browser.button(:value=>"Login").click #submit
  browser.div(:id=>"DivMenu").click
  #sleep 3
  browser.span(:class =>"down").click 
  sleep 3
  browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('hlGenerateStatusReports').click();")
  sleep 3
  browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('Report').click();")
  sleep 3
  optncount = browser.select_list(:id => 'head_ddlClient').options.count
  puts optncount
  i = 0
  while i <= optncount  do
    puts "Inside the loop i = "+i.to_s
    i +=1
    browser.select_list(:id => 'ddlClient').option(:index => i).select
    sleep 3
    browser.button(:value=>"Generate Report").click #submit
    sleep 10
  end
  browser.goto " " //url to logout
rescue Exception => e  
  puts e.message  
  puts e.backtrace.inspect  
end
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. How can we help?

Comment: I need an help to download the files with some specific range using ruby watir script.any help?.please

Comment: Use a loop: `(10..30).each { |i| download_file(i) }`

Comment: hi stefan,there is any chance to pass an arguments in the command prompt.while executing a ruby file.

Comment: @Stefan we might admire and be proud, might not we?

Comment: Spaghetti code my old foe we meet again

Comment: @eswar command line arguments are stored in the global [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#ARGV) array.

Answer (score 0):

I also have download scripts for images etc.
The small part of the one I use here to demonstrate the technique is for 500px.com.

I keep all downloaded files in a textfile and check if allready downloaded against this file. That way you can break off at any moment and resume later.
Of course you could break off if `downloaded` reached a limit.

I don't publish the whole of the script, just what matters regarding your question.

```
def download url
  filename = "#{url[-32..-1]}.jpg"
  if get(url, filename, SAVE_FOLDER)
    File.open(PROGRESS_FILE,'a+'){|f|f.puts filename}
  end
end

PROGRESS_FILE   = './500px.txt'
downloaded = 0
....
response = http.get(path, headers)
json = JSON.parse(response.body)["data"]
processed = File.read(PROGRESS_FILE)
json.each do |item|
  url       = item['images'].last['url']
  signature = url[-32..-1]
  filename  = "#{signature}.jpg"
  # check if the filenames is in the textfile and so was downloaded allready
  unless processed[filename]
    download url
    downloaded += 1
  end
end
```

The file has more than 500 million lines so far and works fast enough (the downloading takes much longer). If I hit a limit I can easily put the lines in a simple database like Sqlite.